# Looping through NetSuite "objects" with FreeMarker

Tags: freemarker, netsuite

I am struggling to deal with a few aspects of the data being "passed" to Advanced PDF Templates in NetSuite and the fact there is no "object browser".  I have seen, using:

```
<#list .data_model?keys as key>
   ${key} = ${.data_model[key]}<br />
</#list>
```

that there are data "objects":

```
companyinformation =
message =
nsfont =
preferences =
record =
record@title = Invoice
subsidiary =
subsidiary@title = Subsidiary
user =
```

Is there anyway to look deeper into each of these objects to see their properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can dump the properties of the objects on the same way, that is, by iterating through their `?keys`, because it's not only for `Map`-s, but for any value that has named subvariables. (Well, assuming the `ObjectWrapper` in the FreeMarker configuration is like that, but let's hope it is for now.)

Because this is going to be recursive, you will want to use a `#macro`. Be careful with infinite recursion though (usually, you want a maximum depth at least).

If FreeMarker is at least 2.3.25, you can also write `<#list something as key, value>`, which is nicer, and supports non-string keys.